# how to give background color for button in android

Tags: android, button, colors

i have three button which is arranged in table row .I gave background for the three button but it wraps the button .

Comment: Post some code for the button please.

Answer (score 2):

For starters [read my blog](http://my.opera.com/HP-45/blog/2010/05/14/button-blues) :-)

Now my suggestion is to use background definitions with gradients. They look nice and are simpler to create then background images. As I said in the blog you need three of them for the button to work as expected. I have a demo for you here: [button_type_0.xml](https://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/uiq3/trunk/Java/FX-603P-Droid/res/drawable/button_type_0.xml)

You will also need to define the colours: [colors.xml](https://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/uiq3/trunk/Java/FX-603P-Droid/res/values/colors.xml)

and dimensions: [dimens.xml](https://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/uiq3/trunk/Java/FX-602P-Droid/res/values/dimens.xml)

you might also want to consider different dimensions for various dpi values. for example I use half size corners and border for ldpi: [ldpi/dimens.xml](https://uiq3.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/uiq3/trunk/Java/FX-602P-Droid/res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml)

Looks all very complicated at the beginning but it is worth it. In the end it will look like this:

[image: HP-45 Emulator]

Comment: i realize that this post is 2 years old, but your links are broken and as a result i cant see your examples..can you please edit?

Answer (score 0):

declare new a new xml in the drawable folder with the image/color you can specify image for each [event state](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).
and you can you can set this xml as you background

if your xml is '`res/drawable/abc.xml`' then set background as

```
android:background="@drawable/abc"
```

You can also use ImageButton

```
<ImageButton
----------------------
android:src="@drawable/youimage" 
 />
```

The benefit for ImageButton is that, no need of different image/color for highlight.